# Upgrade matrix synapse postgresql database from 9.6 to 11

Tags: postgresql, synapse

I have a VM on my server where I host a Matrix synapse homeserver.

Now I need to update postgresql, because version 9.6 is EOL.

The database in `/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main` already has 56 GByte.

I dumped the database in sql files with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DB=synapse
U=irc-bridge
# directory to dump files without trailing slash:
DIR=/home/synapse/postgres-backup
mkdir -p $DIR
TABLES="$(psql -q -d $DB -U $U -t -c "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE' ORDER BY table_name")"
w=$(echo $TABLES|wc -w)
echo $w tables
i=0
for table in $TABLES; do
  i=$((i + 1))
  echo "$i/$w: backup $table ..."
  pg_dump -U $U -t $table $DB | gzip > $DIR/$table.sql.gz;
done;
```

I get about 9 GByte of zipped Files.

What would be the easyest path to upgrade the Postgres cluster up from 9.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to dump the whole database and import it in the new cluster:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dumpall --cluster 9.6/main > dump.sql
sudo -u postgres psql -d postgres --cluster 13/main -f dump.sql
```

see https://decatec.de/linux/postgresql-upgrade-auf-neue-version-durchfuehren

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the upgrade as well, as Synapse, starting from version 1.72.0, dropped support for Postgresql older than version 11.

Context: Our installation is done with docker-compose, in `/opt/synapse`, with the postgres container defined like this:

```
db:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  image: docker.io/postgres:10-alpine                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  shm_size: 1gb                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  restart: unless-stopped                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  environment:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    - POSTGRES_USER=synapse                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_postgres_password
    - POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS=--encoding=UTF-8 --lc-collate=C --lc-ctype=C                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  volumes:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    - ./schemas:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

This means that the postgres data files are in `/opt/synapse/schemas`.

I used https://github.com/tianon/docker-postgres-upgrade to do the postgres data upgrade.

I ran into one problem: not having the role (user) `postgres` in my old (version 11) installation. I resolved that by specifying to the pg_upgrade script to use the role `synapse`, and manually bootstraping the new (version 15) database, because both old and new installation must have the same user available.

Step by step, it goes like this:

1. Backup the data: `cp -a schemas schemas-v11-backup`
2. Create folder structure the way `docker-postgres-upgrade` expects it to have:

```
mkdir -p upgradepg/10/data
mkdir -p upgradepg/15/data
```

3. Copy the old postgres data into the "OLD" directory:
   `cp -a schemas/* upgradepg/10/data/`
4. Clean the `schemas` postgres data folder, so that we can initialize it with postgres version 15 data files: `rm -rf schemas/*`
5. Change the postgres version in `docker-compose.yml` to 15 ( -> whole line is `image: docker.io/postgres:15-alpine`), and start the service with `docker-compose up db`. This will bootstrap the database container with user `synapse` and database `synapse`.
6. `pg_upgrade` will be, however, migrating the old data ( = the old database), and it would fail if there already was a database called `synapse`. We have to delete the database:

```
docker-compose exec db psql -U synapse
\c postgres
drop database synapse;
exit
```

7. Stop the running postgres 15 container (ctrl+c if it is bound to a terminal, otherwise `docker-compose stop db`)
8. Copy the newly bootstrapped postgres 15 data directory into `upgradepg/15/data`: `cp schemas/* upgradepg/15/data/`
9. run the migration tool: `docker run --rm -v /opt/synapse/upgradepg:/var/lib/postgresql tianon/postgres-upgrade:10-to-15 -U synapse` (the -U synapse makes `pg_upgrade` use user `synapse`). The output in terminal should end with following:

```
Upgrade Complete
----------------
Optimizer statistics are not transferred by pg_upgrade.
Once you start the new server, consider running:
    /usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin/vacuumdb -U synapse --all --analyze-in-stages
```

10. Copy the migrated data back to your synapse db container data directory: `cp -a upgradepg/15/data/* schemas/`
11. For some reason, the password for the `synapse` user was not set, leading to synapse not being able to connect to the database. To make sure the password authentication will work, start the db container, and set the `synapse` user's password:

```
docker-compose up db

(in another terminal, in /opt/synapse):

docker-compose exec db psql -U synapse
alter role synapse with password 'your_synapse_pw_from_docker-compose.yml';
exit
```

That's it. For cleanup, remove the `upgradepg` and (after your synapse is running properly:), `schemas-v11-backup`.