# How can I upgrade the postgreSQL from 14 to 15 in kali linux VM?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, postgresql

I am setting up my first VM with debian (x64) and kali linux... I am a windows user but want to learn linux. while upgrading linux using `sudo apt upgrade` I got a message like this.

[image: translated with https://translate.yandex.com]

But I do not really understand what it means. If someone could help me I will be very pleased. (I am a very begginer in Linux)

*Disclaimer: If you do not understand the picture, in resume it says that PostgreSQL 14 is not working more, and I must upgrade to postgresql-15 and postgresql-client-15 and upgrade it clusters with order "pg_upgradecluster"

Comment: Hi! Let me stop you there! Learning Linux is great, but it should not be done using Kali Linux, say not only I and all experienced Linux users I've personally talked to, but also Kali Linux themselves: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/#:~:text=The%20fact%20of%20the%20matter,general%2Dpurpose%20Linux%20desktop%20distribution

Comment: But, the thing is, it is not clear what you mean when you say "with Debian and Kali", because while Kali is based on debian in a way, it is a separate thing with its own special rules and methods. One of the rules is "this is not a Linux that you should use for everyday work, so we don't care if updates break things, or goal is solely to be the right toolkit for a Linux expert with a different Linux somewhere else when they go on a penetration testing excursion, so, boot Kali, penetrate, save data, forget about the stick you've booted from,next time get the newest Kali and put it on a stick"

Comment: I’d recommend two edits: 1) removed the photo and translate it to English as text in a quote block. 2) clarify whether you are using Debian or kali.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture says that PostgreSQL 14 is not working more, and I must upgrade to postgresql-15 and postgresql-client-15 and upgrade it clusters with order `pg_upgradecluster`:

> The PostgreSQL 14 version is deprecated, but the PostgreSQL package
> client or server are still installed. You must install the
> latest versions of the packages (postgresql-15 and
> postgresql-client-15) and update your clusters with the command
> `pg_upgradecluster` (see the man page).
>
> Note that installing postgresql-15 will create
> automatically a default cluster 15/main. You have to delete the
> existing cluster 15 (pg_dropcluster --stop 15) if you want to update
> the 14/main cluster, see the man page for the
> details.
> The old client and server packages are no longer supported.
> You should remove the packages postgresql-14 and postgresql-client-14
> after upgrading any clusters you have.
> For more information see
> /usr/share/doc/postgresql-common/README.Debian.gz

If you didn't use postgres so far, just click "accept" and continue your upgrade.

---

### Upgrade your postgreSQL Database from 14 to 15 on Debian

see [Upgrade your postgreSQL Database from 14 to 15 on Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735327/upgrade-your-postgresql-database-from-14-to-15-on-debian/735328#735328)

---

### Or you dump and re-import your data with

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dumpall --cluster 14/main > ~/backup_postgres_all_dbs.tar
sudo -u postgres psql -d postgres --cluster 15/main -f ~/backup_postgres_all_dbs.tar
```

see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707827/20661