# Upgrade your postgreSQL Database from 14 to 15 on Debian

Tags: debian, postgresql

I wonder how I can upgrade the data from an existing PostgreSQL 14 installation to 15.

I automatically got PG 15 installed via apt, so I see

```
# dpkg -l | grep ii | cut -d" " -f3 | grep postgresql-1

postgresql-14
postgresql-15
```

But the data is still all in PG 14.

There are two services

```
service postgresql@14-main status
```

and

```
service postgresql@15-main status
```

Answer (score 3):

Be sure you are still running on the old 14 cluster, Then **backup your data** with

```
pg_dumpall -F t > ~/backup_postgres_all_dbs.tar
```

Stop the still empty default installed postgreSQL 15 cluster and drop it.

```
pg_dropcluster 15 main --stop
```

Upgrade the 14 cluster to the latest version (which is 15 at the moment writing)

```
pg_upgradecluster 14 main
```

This can take some hours. Once it is finished, check that the upgraded cluster works:

```
service postgresql@14-main stop
service postgresql@15-main start
```

Your 14 cluster should now be “down”. you can verify it running:

```
pg_lsclusters

Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
14  main    5433 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log
15  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/15/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-15-main.log
```

Check if the applications, that use postgreSQL all work (eventually adapt the port in your psql-15 config). If everything is fin then remove the 14 cluster with

```
# !be really sure to call this!
# !DON'T BE TOO FAST!!! # pg_dropcluster 14 main
```

and remove the old packages.

```
apt-get purge postgresql-14 postgresql-client-14
```

*(Note: This most probably also works the same on Kali)*

adapted from: https://www.paulox.net/2022/04/28/upgrading-postgresql-from-version-13-to-14-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish/

Comment: What does the `-F` parameter do in `pg_dumpall` ? It's an invalid option. `t` also doesn't work.
I used this command: `sudo -u postgres pg_dumpall | gzip > /tmp/backup_postgres_all_dbs-$(date +"%Y_%m_%d").gz`, and then moved it afterwards

Comment: I read [here](https://backup.ninja/news/postgresql-backups-what-is-pgdumpall) all the options for pg_dumpall command should be similar to pg_dump command. so it "Format tar". But this could be outdated

Comment: The `-m upgrade` argument to `pg_upgradecluster` will speed it up considerably.

Comment: Why is `-m upgrade` not the default then? Is it somewhat unsafe?

Answer (score 0):

### Or dump and re-import your data with

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dumpall --cluster 14/main > ~/backup_postgres_all_dbs.sql
sudo -u postgres psql -d postgres --cluster 15/main -f ~/backup_postgres_all_dbs.sql
```

see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707827/20661

Comment: I'd rather avoid this method because if something specific has to be done for the upgrade it probably won't be done (eg: template change?, or hook scripts run by pg_upgradecluster?)

Comment: Only if you use vanilla postgreSQL. What application would install hook scripts?

Comment: Couldn't find any on Debian. But It would probably be future proof to run a dedicated upgrade script.